# Exit program with all its processes

Tags: chromium, process

I'm using chromium browser on Ubuntu OS.

When I press the exit button many processes appear still running. Does anyone know how I can stop this browser completely with all its processes when I press exit button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you go into Chromium's settings and uncheck the "Continue running background apps", does that stop the background processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck this in settings, "show advanced settings" somewhere near the bottom:

[image]